# How can I fill an asp.net textbox with a previous asp.net textbox value when the user tabs to it using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, textbox

I have about 60 asp.net textboxes with each of them having an ID like "InputTextBox##".

How can I make it to where the user can tab to the next textbox and have it autofill with the previous textbox's value using JQuery?

I've tried this:

```
$("input[id*='Input']").focusin(function () {
        var $this = $(this);

        if ($this.val() === "") {
            $this.val($this.prevAll("input[id*='Input']").last().val() || $this.attr('value'))
        }
    });
```

But this does nothing.
I was trying to select the id of the textbox on focus by searching for "Input" in the id, but I have gotten nowhere with it.

EDIT:
Here is some of my html to give an idea of what I'm working with:

```
<asp:TableRow>
<asp:TableCell><asp:Label ID="InputLabel2" runat="server" Text="2">
</asp:Label></asp:TableCell>
<asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="InputTextBox2" runat="server" Width="70px" >
</asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="InputTextBox2Y" runat="server" Width="35px" Visible="False" 
Enabled="False"></asp:TextBox>
</asp:TableCell>
<asp:TableCell><asp:Label ID="InputLabel12" runat="server" Text="12">
</asp:Label></asp:TableCell>
<asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="InputTextBox12" runat="server" Width="70px">
</asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="InputTextBox12Y" runat="server" Width="35px" 
Visible="False" Enabled="False"></asp:TextBox>
</asp:TableCell>
<asp:TableCell><asp:Label ID="InputLabel22" runat="server" Text="22">
</asp:Label></asp:TableCell>
<asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="InputTextBox22" runat="server" Width="70px">
</asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="InputTextBox22Y" runat="server" Width="35px" 
Visible="False" Enabled="False"></asp:TextBox>
</asp:TableCell>
<asp:TableCell><asp:Label ID="InputLabel32" runat="server" Text="32">
</asp:Label></asp:TableCell>
<asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="InputTextBox32" runat="server" Width="70px">
</asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="InputTextBox32Y" runat="server" Width="35px" 
Visible="False" Enabled="False"></asp:TextBox>
</asp:TableCell>
<asp:TableCell><asp:Label ID="InputLabel42" runat="server" Text="42">
</asp:Label></asp:TableCell>
<asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="InputTextBox42" runat="server" Width="70px">
</asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="InputTextBox42Y" runat="server" Width="35px" 
Visible="False" Enabled="False"></asp:TextBox>
</asp:TableCell>
<asp:TableCell><asp:Label ID="InputLabel52" runat="server" Text="52">
</asp:Label></asp:TableCell>
<asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="InputTextBox52" runat="server" Width="70px">
</asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="InputTextBox52Y" runat="server" Width="35px" 
Visible="False" Enabled="False"></asp:TextBox>  
</asp:TableCell>
</asp:TableRow>
```

And here is an image of what the table looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FX8Lt.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to auto fill input with value from the previous input on horizontal basis:

```js
$(document).on('focus', 'input[id*=InputTextBox]', function() {
  if ($(this).val() == "") {
    var tdIndex = $(this).closest('td').index();
    if ((tdIndex - 2) >= 0) {
      var prevTd = $(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(tdIndex - 2);
      if (prevTd != null && prevTd != undefined) {
        $(this).val($(prevTd).find('input[id*=InputTextBox]').val());
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><span id="MainContent_InputLabel1">1</span></td>
      <td><input name="ctl00$MainContent$InputTextBox1" type="text" id="MainContent_InputTextBox1" style="width:70px;"></td>
      <td><span id="MainContent_InputLabel11">11</span></td>
      <td><input name="ctl00$MainContent$InputTextBox11" type="text" id="MainContent_InputTextBox11" style="width:70px;"></td>
      <td><span id="MainContent_InputLabel21">21</span></td>
      <td><input name="ctl00$MainContent$InputTextBox21" type="text" id="MainContent_InputTextBox21" style="width:70px;"></td>
      <td><span id="MainContent_InputLabel31">31</span></td>
      <td><input name="ctl00$MainContent$InputTextBox31" type="text" id="MainContent_InputTextBox31" style="width:70px;"></td>
      <td><span id="MainContent_InputLabel41">41</span></td>
      <td><input name="ctl00$MainContent$InputTextBox41" type="text" id="MainContent_InputTextBox41" style="width:70px;"></td>
      <td><span id="MainContent_InputLabel51">51</span></td>
      <td><input name="ctl00$MainContent$InputTextBox51" type="text" id="MainContent_InputTextBox51" style="width:70px;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span id="MainContent_InputLabel2">2</span></td>
      <td><input name="ctl00$MainContent$InputTextBox2" type="text" id="MainContent_InputTextBox2" style="width:70px;"></td>
      <td><span id="MainContent_InputLabel12">12</span></td>
      <td><input name="ctl00$MainContent$InputTextBox12" type="text" id="MainContent_InputTextBox12" style="width:70px;"></td>
      <td><span id="MainContent_InputLabel22">22</span></td>
      <td><input name="ctl00$MainContent$InputTextBox22" type="text" id="MainContent_InputTextBox22" style="width:70px;"></td>
      <td><span id="MainContent_InputLabel32">32</span></td>
      <td><input name="ctl00$MainContent$InputTextBox32" type="text" id="MainContent_InputTextBox32" style="width:70px;"></td>
      <td><span id="MainContent_InputLabel42">42</span></td>
      <td><input name="ctl00$MainContent$InputTextBox42" type="text" id="MainContent_InputTextBox42" style="width:70px;"></td>
      <td><span id="MainContent_InputLabel52">52</span></td>
      <td><input name="ctl00$MainContent$InputTextBox52" type="text" id="MainContent_InputTextBox52" style="width:70px;"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

If you need to auto fill input with value from the previous input on vertical basis:

```js
$(document).on('focus', 'input[id*=InputTextBox]', function() {
  if ($(this).val() == "") {
    var tdIndex = $(this).closest('td').index();
    var rowIndex = $(this).closest('tr').index();
    if (rowIndex > 0) {
      var prevRowCol = $(this).closest('table').find('tr').eq(rowIndex - 1).find('td').eq(tdIndex);
      if (prevRowCol != null && prevRowCol != undefined) {
        $(this).val($(prevRowCol).find('input[id*=InputTextBox]').val());
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><span id="MainContent_InputLabel1">1</span></td>
      <td><input name="ctl00$MainContent$InputTextBox1" type="text" id="MainContent_InputTextBox1" style="width:70px;"></td>
      <td><span id="MainContent_InputLabel11">11</span></td>
      <td><input name="ctl00$MainContent$InputTextBox11" type="text" id="MainContent_InputTextBox11" style="width:70px;"></td>
      <td><span id="MainContent_InputLabel21">21</span></td>
      <td><input name="ctl00$MainContent$InputTextBox21" type="text" id="MainContent_InputTextBox21" style="width:70px;"></td>
      <td><span id="MainContent_InputLabel31">31</span></td>
      <td><input name="ctl00$MainContent$InputTextBox31" type="text" id="MainContent_InputTextBox31" style="width:70px;"></td>
      <td><span id="MainContent_InputLabel41">41</span></td>
      <td><input name="ctl00$MainContent$InputTextBox41" type="text" id="MainContent_InputTextBox41" style="width:70px;"></td>
      <td><span id="MainContent_InputLabel51">51</span></td>
      <td><input name="ctl00$MainContent$InputTextBox51" type="text" id="MainContent_InputTextBox51" style="width:70px;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span id="MainContent_InputLabel2">2</span></td>
      <td><input name="ctl00$MainContent$InputTextBox2" type="text" id="MainContent_InputTextBox2" style="width:70px;"></td>
      <td><span id="MainContent_InputLabel12">12</span></td>
      <td><input name="ctl00$MainContent$InputTextBox12" type="text" id="MainContent_InputTextBox12" style="width:70px;"></td>
      <td><span id="MainContent_InputLabel22">22</span></td>
      <td><input name="ctl00$MainContent$InputTextBox22" type="text" id="MainContent_InputTextBox22" style="width:70px;"></td>
      <td><span id="MainContent_InputLabel32">32</span></td>
      <td><input name="ctl00$MainContent$InputTextBox32" type="text" id="MainContent_InputTextBox32" style="width:70px;"></td>
      <td><span id="MainContent_InputLabel42">42</span></td>
      <td><input name="ctl00$MainContent$InputTextBox42" type="text" id="MainContent_InputTextBox42" style="width:70px;"></td>
      <td><span id="MainContent_InputLabel52">52</span></td>
      <td><input name="ctl00$MainContent$InputTextBox52" type="text" id="MainContent_InputTextBox52" style="width:70px;"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

If you need to auto fill input with value from the previous input regardless of vertical and horizontal direction:

```js
$(document).on('focus', 'input[id*=InputTextBox]', function() {
  if ($(this).val() == "") {
    var tdIndex = $('table td').index($(this).closest('td'));
    if (tdIndex - 2 > 0) {
      var prevTD = $('table td').eq(tdIndex - 2);
      $(this).val($(prevTD).find('input[id*=InputTextBox]').val());
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><span id="MainContent_InputLabel1">1</span></td>
      <td><input name="ctl00$MainContent$InputTextBox1" type="text" id="MainContent_InputTextBox1" style="width:70px;"></td>
      <td><span id="MainContent_InputLabel11">11</span></td>
      <td><input name="ctl00$MainContent$InputTextBox11" type="text" id="MainContent_InputTextBox11" style="width:70px;"></td>
      <td><span id="MainContent_InputLabel21">21</span></td>
      <td><input name="ctl00$MainContent$InputTextBox21" type="text" id="MainContent_InputTextBox21" style="width:70px;"></td>
      <td><span id="MainContent_InputLabel31">31</span></td>
      <td><input name="ctl00$MainContent$InputTextBox31" type="text" id="MainContent_InputTextBox31" style="width:70px;"></td>
      <td><span id="MainContent_InputLabel41">41</span></td>
      <td><input name="ctl00$MainContent$InputTextBox41" type="text" id="MainContent_InputTextBox41" style="width:70px;"></td>
      <td><span id="MainContent_InputLabel51">51</span></td>
      <td><input name="ctl00$MainContent$InputTextBox51" type="text" id="MainContent_InputTextBox51" style="width:70px;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span id="MainContent_InputLabel2">2</span></td>
      <td><input name="ctl00$MainContent$InputTextBox2" type="text" id="MainContent_InputTextBox2" style="width:70px;"></td>
      <td><span id="MainContent_InputLabel12">12</span></td>
      <td><input name="ctl00$MainContent$InputTextBox12" type="text" id="MainContent_InputTextBox12" style="width:70px;"></td>
      <td><span id="MainContent_InputLabel22">22</span></td>
      <td><input name="ctl00$MainContent$InputTextBox22" type="text" id="MainContent_InputTextBox22" style="width:70px;"></td>
      <td><span id="MainContent_InputLabel32">32</span></td>
      <td><input name="ctl00$MainContent$InputTextBox32" type="text" id="MainContent_InputTextBox32" style="width:70px;"></td>
      <td><span id="MainContent_InputLabel42">42</span></td>
      <td><input name="ctl00$MainContent$InputTextBox42" type="text" id="MainContent_InputTextBox42" style="width:70px;"></td>
      <td><span id="MainContent_InputLabel52">52</span></td>
      <td><input name="ctl00$MainContent$InputTextBox52" type="text" id="MainContent_InputTextBox52" style="width:70px;"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

In the given example you are having two adjacent textboxes of which one is hidden from server side itself. If you are enabling it any time, then you need to change `tdIndex - 2` to `tdIndex - 3` as a new column will be rendered.

Comment: So I tried this, but it still did not function for me. If I had the textboxes in an update panel, would that affect this code in any way?

Comment: If all your text boxes are in a single update panel, It will work. But if all are in different panels, it wont work.

Comment: Can you please include the rendered html pieces, So that we can analyse the real problem?

Comment: Edited the post to provide a little more context.

Comment: I can see text boxes to right and to downwards direction. Consider textbox right to label with value '12'. You need to fill it with value of 11 or 2?

Comment: @TroutIn2D : Anyway I have updated three type of filling. You can select any one, suiting your requirement. If anything needs to be updated, please notify

Comment: You are awesome! Your second snippet is working great for me. Thank you for your help!